# Why are all my uploaded files erroring with 404?

Tags: php, wordpress

So, for practice, I'm making a little form which allows users to upload files to my website. I'm using wordpress, and whatever I search in google, I just get links to plugins. Since I'm doing this for practice, using a plugin would defeat the purpose.

So far, what is working is that when a file is submited a folder is created in the root of the wordpress installation, if it doesn't exist. An then, within that folder another one is created for the current user. So now there is a /uploads/ folder in the server, and the file gets uploaded there.
I also put an array in the user meta data. The array contains an associative sub-array at every index which has the file name, path and type in it. I checked in phpMyAdmin, and the user meta data updating also works.

What doesn't work is that all of the files are innacessible. I get the array from the user meta and then for each sub-array I echo

```
<a href="[file_path]">[file_name] -> [file_type]</a>
<img src="[file_path]">Could not load image: [file_name]</img>
```

The first is for text files and the second for images. If I click the link for a text file it gives me the 404 error and the URL looks okay and the image doesn't display.

Below is the code in all of its glorious messiness. I even tried using umask to set all of the permissions to 0777(in the file manager the upload folder gets this permission as well as the specific user, but the files get 0644), as I tought this is what might be causing the error. I really have no idea where to look how to fix this, at all...

```
<?php

  //response generation function
  $response = "";

  //function to generate response
  function my_contact_form_generate_response($type, $message){
    global $response;

    if($type == "success") $response = "<div class='success'>{$message}</div>";
    else $response = "<div class='error'>{$message}</div>";

  }

function check_form() {
    // Get & verify user
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) ) {
        return 'Current user is invalid';
    }

    // Verify/create root upload directory
    $upload_path = ABSPATH . 'uploads/';
    if (!file_exists($upload_path)) {
        $old_mask = umask(0);
        if (!mkdir($upload_path, 0777, true)) {
            return 'Could not create root upload directory';
        }
        umask($old_mask);
    }

    // Verify/create user upload directory
    $current_user_dname = (string)$current_user->display_name;
    $current_user_id = (string)$current_user->ID;
    $upload_path .= $current_user_dname . $current_user_id;
    if ( !file_exists( $upload_path ) ) {
        // Create directory
        $old_mask = umask(0);
        if ( !mkdir( $upload_path, 0777, true ) ) {
            return 'Could not create user upload directory.';
        }
        umask($old_mask);

        // Register in user meta data
        update_user_meta($current_user_id , 'uploaded_files', array());
    }

    $allowed_ftypes = array(
        '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.bmp', '.png', '.gif',
        '.txt', '.pdf'
    );
    $max_filesize = 524288; // 0.5MB

    $file_name = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
    $file_ext = strtolower( substr( $file_name, strpos( $file_name, '.' ), strlen( $file_name ) - 1 ) );

    // Verify file type
    if ( !in_array( $file_ext , $allowed_ftypes ) ) {
        return 'The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.';
    }
    // Verify filesize
    if ( !filesize( $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"] ) > $max_filesize ) {
        return 'The file you attempted to upload is too large.';
    }
    // Verify writing permissions
    if ( !is_writable( $upload_path ) ) {
        return 'You cannot upload the file to the specified directory.';
    }

    $full_path = $upload_path . '/' . $file_name;

    if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], $full_path ) ) {
        // Get simplified file type
        $type = 'text';
        if (array_search($file_ext, $allowed_ftypes) < 5) {
            $type = 'image';
        }

        // Add to meta
        $file_array = get_user_meta($current_user_id , 'uploaded_files', true);
        $file_array_add = array(
            'path' => $full_path,
            'name' => $file_name,
            'type' => $type
        );

        // Check file existence
        $file_exists = false;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($file_array); $i++) {
            $at_i = $file_array[$i];
            if ($at_i['name'] === $file_name) {
                $file_exists = true;
            }
        }

        if (!$file_exists) {
            $file_array[] = $file_array_add;
            update_user_meta($current_user_id , 'uploaded_files', $file_array);
        }

        // Complete
        return 'File uploaded successfuly, view it <a href="' . $full_path . '" title="Your File">here</a>.';
    } else {
            return 'There was an error uploading the file. Please, try again.';
        }
}

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    my_contact_form_generate_response("success", check_form());
}
?>

<style type="text/css">
  .error{
    padding: 5px 9px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }

  .success{
    padding: 5px 9px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    color: green;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }

  form span{
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<div id="respond">
  <?php echo $response; ?>
         <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p>
                <label for="file">Select a file:</label>
                <input type="file" name="userfile" id="file"> <br />
                <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
                <input type="submit" value="upload">
            <p>
        </form>
</div>

<div id="my-files">
    <?php
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) ) {
            echo '<p>Undefined user</p>';
        } else {
            $file_array = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'uploaded_files', true);
            // File array is empty
            if ($file_array === '') {
                echo '<p>No files</p>';
            } else {
                echo '<h3>Files:</h3><br/>';
                $len = count($file_array);
                for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
                    $file_data = $file_array[$i];
                    $f_path = $file_data['path'];
                    $f_name = $file_data['name'];
                    $f_type = $file_data['type'];
                    if ($f_type === 'image') {
                        echo '<img src="' . $f_path . '">Can not get image: ' . $f_name . '</img>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<a href=' . $f_path . '>' . $f_name . ' -> ' . $f_type . '</a><br/>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

EDIT:

Here's my updated .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~mdg17761/druskamdg.com/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?uploads/
RewriteRule . /~mdg17761/druskamdg.com/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The old one didn't have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?uploads/
```

The problem still persits, but I'm posting the .htaccess file as there are multiple wordpress installations, so maybe the RewriteCond above needs to be a tad bit different. I tried mixing in /~mdg17761/druskamdg.com/ in several ways, but I haven't got it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the files are all being successfully uploaded, but accessing the files through a browser is the problem. It sounds like you're running into an issue with the URL rewrites that Wordpress uses. The rewrites start at the root level of your installation, and carry over to sub-directories unless told otherwise.

In the root of your Wordpress installation, take a look at your .htaccess, and add a line that tells it to ignore the subdirectory when doing rewrites (in this case, '/uploads')

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?uploads/
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```